# Legend Formatting not happening via VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Would anyone be kind enough to highlight the flaw in the logic of my code. No errors are thrown but I am not getting the desired result.

**Logic:** The macro will get all properties of all legends of master chart, store it in an array and then apply the same formatting for other charts in the whole ppt from the array.

Code:

```
       Sub FormatLegendsOfCharts(   
        
        Dim NewSel As Selection
        Set NewSel = ActiveWindow.Selection
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim ThisShape As Shape
        Set ThisShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If ThisShape Is Nothing Then GoTo 100:
 
        If ThisShape.HasChart = True Then
        
            Dim ThisChart As Chart
            Set ThisChart = ThisShape.Chart
        
            If ThisChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers Or ThisChart.ChartType = xlLine Then
                Dim GetSourceFormatting() As Variant
                ReDim GetSourceFormatting(ThisChart.SeriesCollection.Count, 8)
                Dim i As Long
                For i = 1 To ThisChart.SeriesCollection.Count
        
                    Dim EachSeries As Series
                    Set EachSeries = ThisChart.SeriesCollection(i)
        
                    GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 0) = EachSeries.Border.Color
                    GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 1) = EachSeries.Border.Weight            
                    GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 2) = EachSeries.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
                    GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 3) = EachSeries.Format.Line.Weight
                    GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 4) = EachSeries.MarkerStyle
                    GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 5) = EachSeries.MarkerSize
                    GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 6) = EachSeries.MarkerBackgroundColor
                    GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 7) = EachSeries.MarkerForegroundColor
                    GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 8) = EachSeries.Name
               Next
        
               Call FormatLegendsInOtherCharts(GetSourceFormatting())
           Else
               MsgBox "Macro only works on line chart."
           End If
        
       Else
           MsgBox "Please select master chart"
       End If
        
        
        MsgBox "Done"
        
        Exit Sub
 100:
        MsgBox "Please select master chart"
        
        
    End Sub
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------
        
    Private Sub FormatLegendsInOtherCharts(Database() As Variant)
        
        
         Dim j As Long
         Dim k As Long
         
         For j = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
         
           Dim ThisSlide As Slide
           Set ThisSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(j) 
           
           For k = 1 To ThisSlide.Shapes.Count
           
            Dim ThisOtherShape As Shape
            Set ThisOtherShape = ThisSlide.Shapes(k)
            
             If ThisOtherShape.HasChart = True Then
            
                    Dim ThisOtherChart As Chart
                    Set ThisOtherChart = ThisOtherShape.Chart
                
                         If ThisOtherChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers Then
                         
                            Call FormattingHappensHere(ThisOtherChart, Database())
                         
                         End If
                   
             End If
           
           Next
         
         Next
    
        End Sub
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------


        
        Private Sub FormattingHappensHere(OurChart As Chart, Databasee() As Variant)
        
        
                    Dim i As Long
                    Dim k As Long
                    
                    For i = 1 To OurChart.SeriesCollection.Count
        
                             Dim EachOtherSeries As Series
                             Set EachOtherSeries = OurChart.SeriesCollection(i)
                             
                               For k = 1 To UBound(Databasee())
                               
                                    If EachOtherSeries.Name = Databasee((k - 1), 8) Then
                                    
                                         EachOtherSeries.Border.Color = Databasee((k - 1), 0)
                                         EachOtherSeries.Border.Weight = Databasee((k - 1), 1)
                                         EachOtherSeries.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Databasee((k - 1), 2)

                                         EachOtherSeries.Format.Line.Weight = Databasee((k - 1), 3)
                                         EachOtherSeries.MarkerStyle = Databasee((k - 1), 4)
                                         EachOtherSeries.MarkerSize = Databasee((k - 1), 5)
                                         EachOtherSeries.MarkerBackgroundColor = Databasee((k - 1), 6)
                                         EachOtherSeries.MarkerForegroundColor = Databasee((k - 1), 7)
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    End If
                               
                               
                               Next
                             
                            
                              Set EachOtherSeries = Nothing
        
                    Next
        
        
        
        End Sub
```

Comment: Which MsgBox message are you getting?

Comment: For a simpler solution, consider creating a chart template with your preferred formatting, then applying that to all charts. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-a-custom-chart-as-a-template-259a5f9d-a9ec-4b3f-94b6-9f5e55187f2a

Comment: @TimWilliams The one which says "Done", just above the error handling block i.e the label 100

Comment: @JohnKorchok That is not really feasible in my case because unfortunately it is not a one shoe fits all situation.

Comment: `Set ThisSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)` is this supposed to be `Set ThisSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(j)` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks. It is supposed to be j not 1. Will update that. However the problem still remains though. Weird error. Never have I faced such a quirk.

Comment: The only thing I'd suggest is to put a bunch of breaks and run the code, then see what parts actually are reached.

Comment: @TimWilliams I was wondering, maybe the code is indeed getting executed because when run line-by-line, every line is getting executed and no error is thrown. That means this is probably a case of logical error. Will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```vb
If ThisOtherChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers Then
    Call FormattingHappensHere(ThisOtherChart, Database())
End If
```

but you probably meant:

```
If ThisOtherChart.ChartType = xlLine Or ThisOtherChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers Then
```

EDIT: this worked for me (some refactoring for clarity)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FormatLegendsOfCharts()
        
     Dim MasterChart As Chart, pres As Presentation
     Dim GetSourceFormatting() As Variant, i As Long
     
     Set pres = ActivePresentation
     Set MasterChart = SelectedChart()
     If MasterChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

     ReDim GetSourceFormatting(MasterChart.SeriesCollection.Count, 8)
     For i = 1 To MasterChart.SeriesCollection.Count
         With MasterChart.SeriesCollection(i)
             GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 0) = .Border.Color
             GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 1) = .Border.Weight
             GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 2) = .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
             GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 3) = .Format.Line.Weight
             GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 4) = .MarkerStyle
             GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 5) = .MarkerSize
             GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 6) = .MarkerBackgroundColor
             GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 7) = .MarkerForegroundColor
             GetSourceFormatting((i - 1), 8) = .Name
         End With
    Next
    FormatLegendsInOtherCharts pres, GetSourceFormatting
       
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
   
        
'get the user-selected chart (or Nothing if no valid selection)
Private Function SelectedChart() As Chart
    Dim ThisShape As Shape
    Dim ThisChart As Chart
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ThisShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ThisShape Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please select a Line chart"
        Exit Function
    Else
        If Not ThisShape.HasChart Then
            MsgBox "Please select a Line chart"
            Exit Function
        Else
            Set ThisChart = ThisShape.Chart
            If Not OKChart(ThisChart) Then
                MsgBox "Macro only works on line chart."
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set SelectedChart = ThisChart
End Function


'check chart type
Private Function OKChart(cht As Chart)
    OKChart = cht.ChartType = xlLine Or cht.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
End Function

Private Sub FormatLegendsInOtherCharts(pres As Presentation, Database() As Variant)
    Dim j As Long, k As Long, ThisOtherChart As Chart
    Dim ThisSlide As Slide, ThisOtherShape As Shape
    
    For j = 1 To pres.Slides.Count
        Set ThisSlide = pres.Slides(j)
        For k = 1 To ThisSlide.Shapes.Count
            Set ThisOtherShape = ThisSlide.Shapes(k)
            If ThisOtherShape.HasChart = True Then
                Set ThisOtherChart = ThisOtherShape.Chart
                If OKChart(ThisOtherChart) Then
                    FormattingHappensHere ThisOtherChart, Database()
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
        
Private Sub FormattingHappensHere(OurChart As Chart, Databasee() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    
    For i = 1 To OurChart.SeriesCollection.Count
        With OurChart.SeriesCollection(i)
            For k = 1 To UBound(Databasee())
                If .Name = Databasee((k - 1), 8) Then
                    .Border.Color = Databasee((k - 1), 0)
                    .Border.Weight = Databasee((k - 1), 1)
                    .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Databasee((k - 1), 2)
                    .Format.Line.Weight = Databasee((k - 1), 3)
                    .MarkerStyle = Databasee((k - 1), 4)
                    .MarkerSize = Databasee((k - 1), 5)
                    .MarkerBackgroundColor = Databasee((k - 1), 6)
                    .MarkerForegroundColor = Databasee((k - 1), 7)
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much Tim. 
I really like how neat & robust your code is. 

Also I could get my code working by tweaking how 2-D array was being passed. I changed the code from  *Call FormatLegendsInOtherCharts(**GetSourceFormatting()**)*   to   *Call FormatLegendsInOtherCharts(**GetSourceFormatting**)* and to my surprise just removing the () worked. However I don't understand why it works. So if you have any insights on this, kindly direct me to some sources.